# Download files from multiple FTP folders in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ftp

Is there a way to dlownload filed from multiple folders in FTP location using SSIS. I know to download files from a particular folder. But there are multiple folders that I want the SSIS to traverse through on FTP location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to put each of your source folders in variables within your package. This would allow you to set up a Loop Container for each variable and pass each path in as a parameter to your ftp task. There would be some overhead because you would be building and destroying the ftp connection with each loop, but that would get you to a parameterized solution.