# downloading multiple files to multiple folder using ssis from sftp

Tags: c#, ssis, ftp, script-task

I am trying to download multiple files that are located in multiple folders from an FTP site into multiple folders on a specific drive using FTP task and script task in SSIS. I am not downloading the files into one specific folder. I have looked everywhere and I could not find any good information. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And what are the links between the files and folders?  Do they share some naming part?  Or are the destination folders the same name as the source folders for each file?  Need a good bit more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download files from multiple FTP folders in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110156/download-files-from-multiple-ftp-folders-in-ssis)

Comment: The folders and the file share the same prefix. For instance,  abc_20170531.txt would go to abc folder. I have tried using source path parameters but it only applies to one specific prefix. Thanks

Comment: Tab Alleman, I will have more than 30 folders so I am trying to see if there is a more efficient way of downloading them before creating 30 foreach loop for each folder. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hmen Are you grabbing all files in all folders off the source FTP?  Meaning.. is there an umbrella folder that contains all the subfolders that you want to grab from, and you can grab everything under that umbrella folder without filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not required to use a script task for some reason, then here is what you want to do:

1. Create a Foreach Loop Container
2. Under the `Collection` tab, `Folder` field, browse to the folder that contains all of the subfolders that you are pulling files from off your source FTP. (This is making the assumption that such a folder exists, which hopefully it does or you can create one)
3. Check the `Traverse Subfolders` box, and choose `Fully Qualified`
4. Under the `Variable Mappings` tab, create a variable `@FileNameWithPath` or whatever you want to call it.  Index default is fine.
5. Create a package variable called `FileName`
6. Set the expression of `FileName` to this, which will remove the path:

`RIGHT(@[User::FileNameWithPath], FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileNameWithPath]), "\\", 1 )-1)`

7. Create a package variable called `FilePrefix`
8. Make an expression to pull the prefix out of the `FileName`.  It will be this, if you're grabbing everything before the first underscore:

`LEFT( @[User::FileName],FINDSTRING(((DT_WSTR, 150) @[User::FileName] ), "_", 1)-1)`

9. Create another variable called `DestinationFolder`.
10. Use the `FilePrefix` variable you just created to build the expression for `DestinationFolder`.  It will be this:

`"\\Your destination FTP\" + @[User::FilePrefix]`

11. Within your Foreach Loop Container, add a `File System Task`
12. Set the `File System Task` to a move or copy, whatever you need, with a `Source Variable` of `FileNameWithPath`, and a destination variable of `DestinationFolder`

Comment: Thank you for the info but is there a way for the foreach loop to connect to the FTP server?  How do you make the foreach loop to connect to FTP remote path? I did not know that was possible. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help - to connect to the FTP server, you should only need to put the full path into step 2 above.  If it require special credentials, you may also need to map the FTP as a network drive on the server running SSIS. @Hmen

Comment: Thank you! I will try mapping it as a next work drive and get back to you if I have any questions.